# Lost after a socket.io upgrade: Websocket keeps disconnecting

Tags: node.js, websocket, redis, socket.io, nestjs

Everything started with the need to upgrade our Redis library as the one we use in the cloud is going to stop supporting the old version we've got.

So we updated a few dependencies and some relied on others... So we ended up upgrading from node 16 to 20, upgrading nestjs from 9.2.1 to 10.3.1 and some others:

```
"@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "7.6.1",
"@nestjs/websockets": "7.6.1",
```

to

```
"@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "10.3.1",
"@nestjs/websockets": "10.3.1",
```

Then we removed these lines

```
"socket.io": "2.3.0",
"socket.io-redis": "5.2.0",
```

and finally migrated from

```
"socket.io-client": "2.3.0",
```

to

```
"socket.io-client": "4.7.4",
```

Now, the issue is that for some reason, after a very short time like 30s to 1mn, the websockets disconnects for some reason. And despite digging into this for a day and a half (thinking it was a Redis issue at first but looks like it's just the first step client to server websocket), I haven't been able to find anything.

I have been taking a deep look here: https://socket.io/docs/v4/troubleshooting-connection-issues but same, I haven't managed to make it work.

Client side:

```
const socket = io(this.url, {
  query,
  secure: true,
  transports: ['websocket'],
  forceNew: false, // use separate sockets (helpful for debugging and potentially resilience)
  auth: { token },
  reconnection: true,
  timeout: 20_000,
  requestTimeout: 10_000,
});
```

As for server side, in order to create the socket and use Redis I've got the following:

```
import { IoAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-socket.io';
import { ServerOptions } from 'socket.io';
import { createAdapter } from '@socket.io/redis-adapter';
import { createClient } from 'redis';
import { INestApplicationContext } from '@nestjs/common';

export class WebsocketAdapter extends IoAdapter {
  constructor(appOrHttpServer: INestApplicationContext, private redisHost: string) {
    super(appOrHttpServer);
  }

  private adapterConstructor: ReturnType<typeof createAdapter>;

  async connectToRedis(): Promise<void> {
    const pubClient = createClient({ url: `redis://${this.redisHost}:6379` });
    const subClient = pubClient.duplicate();

    pubClient.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('[pubClient] connect!');
    });
    pubClient.on('error', () => {
      console.log('[pubClient] error!');
    });
    pubClient.on('end', () => {
      console.log('[pubClient] end!');
    });
    pubClient.on('reconnecting', () => {
      console.log('[pubClient] reconnecting!');
    });
    pubClient.on('ready', () => {
      console.log('[pubClient] ready!');
    });

    subClient.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('[subClient] connect!');
    });
    subClient.on('error', () => {
      console.log('[subClient] error!');
    });
    subClient.on('end', () => {
      console.log('[subClient] end!');
    });
    subClient.on('reconnecting', () => {
      console.log('[subClient] reconnecting!');
    });
    subClient.on('ready', () => {
      console.log('[subClient] ready!');
    });

    await Promise.all([pubClient.connect(), subClient.connect()]);

    this.adapterConstructor = createAdapter(pubClient, subClient);
  }

  override createIOServer(port: number, options?: ServerOptions): any {
    const server = super.createIOServer(port, { ...options, pingTimeout: 10_000, maxHttpBufferSize: 1e6 });
    server.adapter(this.adapterConstructor);
    return server;
  }
}
```

I think the above is very similar to NestJS doc for the demo on how to use Redis: https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/adapter

Does anyone see something wrong in my configuration?

To be honest I feel like I'm getting pretty confused with the config both on the backend and the frontend, for example with

```
  timeout: 20_000,
  requestTimeout: 10_000,
```

Painful upgrade, any help appreciated! Happy to add some more code if you think there are parts that'd be relevant. Thanks!

EDIT:

Based on the first comment I have double checked for incompatibilities of versions between the client and the server by [looking at the resolution of dependencies](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-installation/#version-compatibility) in my yarn.lock and I think it looks ok, I'm using `socket.io@4.7.4` and `socket.io-client@4.7.4`.

For completeness, here's the whole list:

```
socket.io-adapter@~2.5.2:
  version "2.5.2"
  resolved "https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-adapter/-/socket.io-adapter-2.5.2.tgz#5de9477c9182fdc171cd8c8364b9a8894ec75d12"
  integrity sha512-87C3LO/NOMc+eMcpcxUBebGjkpMDkNBS9tf7KJqcDsmL936EChtVva71Dw2q4tQcuVC+hAUy4an2NO/sYXmwRA==
  dependencies:
    ws "~8.11.0"

socket.io-client@4.7.4, socket.io-client@^4.4.1:
  version "4.7.4"
  resolved "https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/-/socket.io-client-4.7.4.tgz#5f0e060ff34ac0a4b4c5abaaa88e0d1d928c64c8"
  integrity sha512-wh+OkeF0rAVCrABWQBaEjLfb7DVPotMbu0cgWgyR0v6eA4EoVnAwcIeIbcdTE3GT/H3kbdLl7OoH2+asoDRIIg==
  dependencies:
    "@socket.io/component-emitter" "~3.1.0"
    debug "~4.3.2"
    engine.io-client "~6.5.2"
    socket.io-parser "~4.2.4"

socket.io-parser@~4.2.4:
  version "4.2.4"
  resolved "https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-parser/-/socket.io-parser-4.2.4.tgz#c806966cf7270601e47469ddeec30fbdfda44c83"
  integrity sha512-/GbIKmo8ioc+NIWIhwdecY0ge+qVBSMdgxGygevmdHj24bsfgtCmcUUcQ5ZzcylGFHsN3k4HB4Cgkl96KVnuew==
  dependencies:
    "@socket.io/component-emitter" "~3.1.0"
    debug "~4.3.1"

socket.io@4.7.4, socket.io@^4.4.1:
  version "4.7.4"
  resolved "https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io/-/socket.io-4.7.4.tgz#2401a2d7101e4bdc64da80b140d5d8b6a8c7738b"
  integrity sha512-DcotgfP1Zg9iP/dH9zvAQcWrE0TtbMVwXmlV4T4mqsvY+gw+LqUGPfx2AoVyRk0FLME+GQhufDMyacFmw7ksqw==
  dependencies:
    accepts "~1.3.4"
    base64id "~2.0.0"
    cors "~2.8.5"
    debug "~4.3.2"
    engine.io "~6.5.2"
    socket.io-adapter "~2.5.2"
    socket.io-parser "~4.2.4"
```

Comment: for my case is that I have incompatible version between client and server lib, socket.io-client v4.x.x while the server side socket.io v2.x.x, after upgrading the issue solved. https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-installation/#version-compatibility

Comment: Thanks! see my edit at the bottom of the question but I think it should all be ok based on the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer myself.

We were upgrading from socket io 2 to 4 and we forgot about one of the required changes.

Described here: https://socket.io/docs/v3/migrating-from-2-x-to-3-0#the-socket-instance-will-no-longer-forward-the-events-emitted-by-its-manager

```
Before:
socket.on("reconnect_attempt", () => {});

After:
socket.io.on("reconnect_attempt", () => {});
```